# Gradle Sync Failed: Xposed Module Framework

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, xposed, xposed-framework

I want to build an Xposed Module but i am not getting past the Gradle build.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simple">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <!--Xposed Framework-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedmodule"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposeddescription"
            android:value="Change IMEI"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedminversion"
            android:value="53" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simple"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 29
        versionName "2.351"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//xposed framework

    compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82'
    compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82:sources'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle Sync Error Message :

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not download api.jar (de.robv.android.xposed:api:82)
>
> Open File
>
> Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath':
>   Could not download api.jar (de.robv.android.xposed:api:82)
>
> Open File
>
> Show Details

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i finally got it to work by removing these :

```
dependencies { 
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

   //xposed framework
   compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82'
   compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82:sources'
}
```

from my list of dependencies